# VBA How to skip specific rows when uploading

Tags: excel, vba

```
                 **Column 1  Column2  Column 3 Column 4 ETC**

**Row 1**           100        200      330        4000   
**Row 2**           4678       5744     5333       8000

**Row 3**           

**Row 4**           100      120       1600        900 

**Row 5**           

**Row 6**           4477      237       220         3200

**Row 7**

ETC
```

This is an example table.
What I'm looking to do is skip certain rows, as you can see Row 5 has no data, so I don't want to include this,but I need it to continue so I can get all the data for Row 6, Row 7 etc etc.
I am uploading data from VBA and excel to SQL.
Have tried an If Statement 
        If sht.Cells(lRow, 1) = "" Then ExitSub

Have tried changing all blank spaces to Nulls - but some of the cells have formulas in them, so aren't Null values but also don't upload.

I presume it is an easy fix and I'm just missing something obvious. 
Any help would be great.

Comment: How do you use endsub and exitsub? What are they?

Comment: For example, I couldn't put an IF statement in saying 'If sht.cells (lRow, 2) = "" Then ExitSub because I need it to continue to upload the rest of the data

Comment: Fill in a formula off the right side, sort on the formula and then delete the formula column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip the row, but continue to the rest of the data then your code needs to be

```
If sht.Cells(lRow, 1) = "" Then lRow = lRow + 1
EndIf
```

Presuming this is part of a loop? If you can post the whole VBA code that would be helpful.

A good code for uploading data that I use is as follows:

```
Sub export_entirexref_to_sql()

Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RowNo As Long
Dim i, x As Long
Dim C1, C2, C3, C4 As String
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim strFile As Variant
Dim shtname As String
Dim strSQL As String
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
If strFile = False Then
Exit Sub
Else: End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' *** Open workbooks first ***
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
    shtname = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
    lastrow = wbk.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Sheets(shtname)

    'Open a connection to SQL Server
    conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxxxxx\xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxx; Password=xxxxxx; "

    ' Delete table data
    conn.Execute "TRUNCATE TABLE EcommerceXRefMapping_C_copy;"

    'Skip the header row
    RowNo = 2

    'Loop until empty cell in Col 1
    Do Until .Cells(RowNo, 1) = ""
        i = i + 1
        C1 = .Cells(RowNo, 1)
        C2 = .Cells(RowNo, 2)
        C3 = .Cells(RowNo, 3)
        C4 = .Cells(RowNo, 4)

        'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table

        strSQL = strSQL + "insert into EcommerceXRefMapping_C_copy ([EquivalentPartNumber_C], [Manufacturer_C], [CatamacPartNumber_C], [Notes_C]) values ('" & C1 & "', '" & C2 & "', '" & C3 & "', '" & C4 & "');"

        conn.Execute strSQL

        RowNo = RowNo + 1

    Loop

    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

    End With

    wbk.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You would just add the IF statement in here

```
        conn.Execute strSQL


        RowNo = RowNo + 1

        If sht.Cells(RowNo, 1) = "" Then RowNo = RowNo + 1
        EndIf

    Loop
```